# How to run multiple Rack::Handler::WEBrick in one Sinatra/Grape file

Tags: sinatra, rack, grape-api

Basically I have multiple API applications in one Sinatra / GrapeAPI file

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'grape'
require 'webrick'
require 'webrick/https'
require 'openssl'

CERT_PATH = '/opt/myCA/server/'

class WebApp  < Sinatra::Base
  post '/' do
    "Hellow, world!"
  end            
end

class Api1  < Grape::API
  get '/test1' do
     {xyz: 'test1' }
  end            
end

class Api2  < Grape::API
  get '/test2' do
    {xyz: 'test2' }
  end          
end

webrick_options1 = {
        :Port               => 8443,
        :Logger             => WEBrick::Log::new($stderr, WEBrick::Log::DEBUG),
        :DocumentRoot       => "/ruby/htdocs",
        :SSLEnable          => true,
        :SSLVerifyClient    => OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE,
        :SSLCertificate     => OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(  File.open(File.join(CERT_PATH, "my-server.crt")).read),
        :SSLPrivateKey      => OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(          File.open(File.join(CERT_PATH, "my-server.key")).read),
        :SSLCertName        => [ [ "CN",WEBrick::Utils::getservername ] ]
}
webrick_options2 = {...}

Rack::Handler::WEBrick.run Api1, webrick_options1 # this will work
Rack::Handler::WEBrick.run Api2, webrick_options2 # but when I try another one, 
                                                 # the other will not
```

Grape gem is recommending to use cascade:

```
run Rack::Cascade.new [Api1, Api2, WebApp]
```

However this will ignore my precious SSL settings.

How can I run multiple server configurations?

Comment: I asked a similar (I believe) question, and this was the answer I got: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16348440/335847

Comment: @iain thx, I was afraid that this will be the case. I'll try unicorn.

Comment: Is it just for the SSL or to run several servers? The SSL is probably best handled by a proxy like Nginx anyway.

Comment: @iain I agree, good point, however I'm doing something really stupid: a simple replica of API (our clients), upon which while developing the main project I make all the requests. So this is just Sinatra app on my localhost, not the real API. Yes I could configure localhost to use NginX it's just I'm trying to avoid that if possible so that other developers don't have to configure NginX just to  use this "dummy API". (at this point we don't us Chef or Docker that would simplify this )

Comment: Yeah, Chef/Docker/Puppet et al would be a good idea, but the Nginx install isn't bad. You really just need the config file, and from having tried something similar, it's definitely easier! :)

Comment: @iain can you please create brief answer with what we discussed here (that it's not possible with webrick, to use Unicorn on other more comprehensive server, or use NginX)? so I can accept it (so you get the credits) ... I guess you covered pretty much all the possible cases :)

Comment: Sure, but it made me think that a reverse proxy for Ruby would be good, and checked to see if anyone had done one (which I should've done in the first place) http://rubygems.org/gems/rack-reverse-proxy. If that works then you can have the honour of answering :)