# How to run Rails server on different ports with address on Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to run my Rails server on different ports with different addresses. I need to run it on port `8888` and address `10.XX.XX.XXX` for all time, in other words, once I start the server, it should run until the server is not stop [sic]. I am running this on Ubuntu machine. Please help me resolve this problem.

Comment: You could try to run it on `rails s -p 8888` [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9263951/2581266)

Comment: Use `rails s -p 8888 -b 10.xx.xx.xxx`. Of course such address must be locally available. If it doesn't work please dump here this command's output to recognize by us what 'not working' means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
rails s -p 8888 -b 10:xx:xx:xx
```

And if you want to run the server in background, then use

```
rails s -p 8888 -b 10:xx:xx:xx -D
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to run it on `rails s -p 8888` and it will be available on your server address on port `xxx.xx.xxx.xx:8888`

Comment: I have tried this its not working in different address.